# "Implementation of Border Length Animation Effect on Mouse Hover for a Button in Material-UI"

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, css-animations

I'm currently working with Material-UI and aiming to customize a component. Specifically, I'd like to achieve a 'Border Length Animation' effect when the mouse hovers over the button. Despite my efforts, I haven't been able to implement this animation as desired.

Example

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5mabAgEoD6A

Complete code

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/admiring-scooby-shcq42?file=%2Fsrc%2FDemo.js

```
const ImageButton = styled(ButtonBase)(({ theme }) => ({
  position: "relative",
  height: 200,
  [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
    width: "100% !important", // Overrides inline-style
    height: 100,
  },
  "&:hover, &.Mui-focusVisible": {
    zIndex: 1,
    "& .MuiImageBackdrop-root": {
      opacity: 0.15,
    },
    "& .MuiImageMarked-root": {
      opacity: 0,
    },
    "& .MuiTypography-root": {
      border: "4px solid currentColor",
    },
  },
}));
  <Typography
              component="span"
              variant="subtitle1"
              color="inherit"
              sx={{
                position: "relative",
                p: 4,
                pt: 2,
                pb: (theme) => `calc(${theme.spacing(1)} + 6px)`,
              }}
            >
              <ImageMarked className="MuiImageMarked-root" />
   </Typography>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code provided, you are missing several key bits of code. You will want to add:

```js
"&::before": {
  content: '""',
  borderTop: "2px solid white",
  borderRight: "2px solid white",
  animation: "borderTopRight 3s infinite alternate",
},
"@keyframes borderTopRight": {
  "0%": {
    width: "0px",
    height: "0px",
  },
  "25%": {
    width: "200px",
    height: "0px",
  },
  "50%": {
    width: "200px",
    height: "48px",
  },
  "100%": {
    width: "200px",
    height: "48px",
  },
},

"&::after": {
  content: '""',
  borderTop: "2px solid white",
  borderRight: "2px solid white",
  animation: "borderBottomLeft 3s infinite alternate",
},
"@keyframes borderBottomLeft": {
  "0%": {
    width: "0px",
    height: "0px",
    opacity: 0,
  },
  "50%": {
    width: "0px",
    height: "0px",
    opacity: 0,
  },
  "50.1%": {
    width: "0px",
    height: "0px",
    opacity: 1,
  },
  "75%": {
    width: "200px",
    height: "0px",
    opacity: 1,
  },
  "100%": {
    width: "200px",
    height: "48px",
    opacity: 1,
  },
},
```

to the styled component that you wish to animate.

See the source code from the video: [Create Border Length Animation with Pure CSS](https://redstapler.co/create-border-length-animation-with-pure-css/)